# How implement types properly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I'm new to Typescript and have been doing a refactor a colleague code, I'm currently doing a typecheck and removing all `any` types. The goal is to make an MSGraph API call and return the a `JSON` file that translated into `BirthdayPerson` with a name, birthday date and a ID

I've been trying to a assign a type instead of any in the following code, but whether I assign `number`, `string` or any other type a different error will show up.
Perhaps I'm not tackling the solution correctly:

`graph.ts`

```
 * @param accessToken
 * @param endpoint url to call from MS Graph
 */
async function callMsGraph(accessToken: string, endpoint: string) {
  const headers = new Headers();
  const bearer = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

  headers.append('Authorization', bearer);

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers,
  };
  try {
    return fetch(endpoint, options);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
}
export const callMsGraphWithoutPagination = async (
  accessToken: string,
  url: string,
  dataToReturn: any[] = []
): Promise<any[]> => {
  try {
    const data = await callMsGraph(accessToken, url);
    const dataJson = await data.json();
    const newData = dataToReturn.concat(dataJson.value);
    if (dataJson['@odata.nextLink']) {
      const NEXT_URL = dataJson['@odata.nextLink'].split('/v1.0')[1];
      return await callMsGraphWithoutPagination(
        accessToken,
        process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPH_URL + NEXT_URL,
        newData
      );
    }
    return dataToReturn.concat(dataJson.value);
  } catch (error) {
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
    console.error(error);
    /* eslint-enable no-console */
    throw error;
  }
};

export default callMsGraph;
```

`useUsers.tsx`

```
export const useUsers = () => {
  const token = useToken();
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState<BirthdayPerson[]>([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      callMsGraphWithoutPagination(token, graphConfig.usersEndpoint).then(async (data: any) => {
        const processedData: any[] = await Promise.all(
          data.map(async (element: any) => {
            const user = await callMsGraph(token, graphConfig.userBirthdayEndpoint(element.id));
            const userJson = await user.json();
            const image = await callMsGraph(token, graphConfig.userPhotoEndpoint(element.id));
            const blob = await image.blob();

            const returnElement: BirthdayPerson = {
              displayName: element.displayName,
              birthday: userJson.value,
              id: element.id,
            };
            if (blob !== null) {
              window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
              returnElement.picture = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            }
            return returnElement;
          })
        );
        setUsers([].concat(...processedData));
      });
    }
  }, [token]);
  return users;
};
```

`helpers.ts`

```
interface IUpdateData {
  slideCount: number;
}

const sortAndFilterBirthdays = (people: BirthdayPerson[], daysToGet: number) =>
  people
    .sort((firstEl, secondEl) => sortDate(firstEl.birthday, secondEl.birthday))
    .filter(({ birthday }) => filterByAmountOfDays({ date: birthday, daysAfter: daysToGet }));

const getBirthdays: any = (people: BirthdayPerson[], daysToGet: number) => {
  const validBirthdays = people.filter((element: any) => {
    const year = moment(element.birthday).year();
    return year !== 0;
  });
  const result = sortAndFilterBirthdays(validBirthdays, daysToGet);

  // if it's okay
  if (result.length > 1 && daysToGet <= 30) {
    return result;
  }

  // if not okay, filters by future dates, concats with 'next year' dates, returns 2 dates
  const fallbackResult = validBirthdays
    .sort((firstEl, secondEl) => sortDate(firstEl.birthday, secondEl.birthday))
    .filter((person: BirthdayPerson) => {
      const currentYear = moment().year();

      const date = moment(person.birthday, DATE_FORMAT).set('years', currentYear);
      return moment().diff(date, 'days') <= 0;
    });

  return fallbackResult.concat(validBirthdays).splice(0, 2);
};
```

Any help or indication would be great!

From all the changes I've done another object will complain that `Type 'x' is not assignable to type 'string'`

Comment: You probably have to rewrite the `callMsGraph` function so that it doesn't return `unknown`. Although you didn't provide its code, so I can't tell exactly how and whether you can do it at all without refactoring a lot of code. It wouldn't be hard if it just returned plain data, but looking at its usage it seems like it returns a `Response` object?

Comment: Hi Alex. Just added the `callMsGraph` function to the question, it's the first function in the first set of code. Exactly! It returns a `Response` object. Was able to tackle the ùnknown`by adding a `Promise`in `callMsGraphWithoutPagination`and a `throw error` in callMsGraph

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider providing a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  And *minimal* is important here; you should suppress any code not directly related to your problem, possibly by rewriting it so that it does less stuff.  And unless your question is *about* modules, you should edit the code so that it can all coexist in a single file.  The overwhelming majority of TS code issues on SO can be demonstrated in code that fits on a single screen at once; that is, fewer than, say, 60 lines of code.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to somehow type responses from API, because right now, as you have seen, call to `.json()` on `Response` object returns `unknown`, which make sense because no one knows what response the server returns. You may know what response it is expected to return, but not what it actually does.

Ideally therefore you need a parser that will verify that the response has correct structure and throws an error otherwise. There are libraries such as `superstruct`, `yup`, `joi` and others which you can use for this. Of course this is a lot of work and will need refactoring. Or if you don't care enough you can just cast the response object to appropriate type, but then if server returns something unexpected and the application cannot handle it, it's your fault.

- Example with response parsing using [superstruct](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/superstruct)

  ```
  import {string, number, create, Infer} from 'superstruct'

  // I assume `BirthdayUser` is just a string, but you can type more complex objects as well
  const BirthdayUser = string()
  // This is so that you don't have to list fields twice: once
  // for the parser and once for typescript
  type BirthdayUser = Infer<typeof BirthdayUser>

  // Then use the parser
  const response = await callMsGraph(acessToken, url)
  const userJson = await response.json()
  // user variable has inferred appropriate type, and if the response doesn't 
  // comply with the definition of `BirthdayUser` an error will be thrown
  // Also I assume MS graph doesn't just return plain value but wraps it in an object with `value` field, so writing it here
  const user = create(userJson, object({ value: BirthdayUser }))
  ```
- Example of "I don't care enough" solution

  ```
  type BirthdayUser = string

  const response = await callMsGraph(accessToken, url)
  // Same thing with wrapping into object with `value` field
  const userJson = (await response.json()) as {value: BirthdayUser}
  ```

This is a bit awkward, because API call returns `Response` object and not the actual data. It might be easier to work with if you move parsing and casting logic inside of `callMsGraph`. It's not obligatory of course, but I still provide an example because after that you need to type `callMsGraphWithoutPagination` and it will use the same idea

```
import {object, create, Struct} from 'superstruct'

async function callMsGraphParsed<T>(
  accessToken: string, 
  url: string, 
  // Since we need information about object structure at runtime, just making function
  // generic is not enough, you need to pass the parser structure as an argument
  struct: Struct<T>
) {
  // ...
  
  const response = await fetch(...)
  const json = await response.json()
  // Same, verifies that response complies to provided structure, if it
  // does returns type object (of type `T`), otherwise throws an error
  return create(json, object({ value: struct }))
}

async function callMsGraphLazy<T>(accessToken: string, url: string) {
  // ...
  const response = await fetch(...)
  const json = await response.json()
  return json as {value: T} 
}
```

However I only call `.json()` here, if you want to use this solution, you will then need either a different function or another argument if you also want it to call `.blob()` for some API calls.

Now you type `callMsGraphWithoutPagination` using in the same way:

```
export const callMsGraphWithoutPaginationParsed = async <T>(
  accessToken: string,
  url: string,
  dataToReturn: T[] = [],
  struct: Struct<T>,
): Promise<T[]> => {
  // If you rewrote `callMsGraph` to use parsing
  const dataJson = await callMsGraph(accessToken, url, struct);
  const newData = dataToReturn.concat(dataJson.value);
  // ...
}

export const callMsGraphWithoutPaginationLazy= async <T>(
  accessToken: string,
  url: string,
  dataToReturn: T[] = [],
): Promise<T[]> => {
  // If you left `callMsGraph` as is
  const data = await callMsGraph(accessToken, url);
  const dataJson = (await data.json()) as {value: T}
  const newData = dataToReturn.concat(dataJson.value);
  // ...
}
```

Then use it

```
// Not sure if you are requesting `BirthdayUser` array here or some other entity, so change it to whatever you expect to receive
callMsGraphWithoutPagination<BirthdayUser>(token, graphConfig.usersEndpoint).then(async (data) => {
  // "data" is inferred to have type BirthdayUser[]
  data.map(element => {
    // "element" is inferred to have type BirthdayUser
  })
})
```

Also everywhere I wrote "I assume" and "Not sure" is missing info that you should probably have provided in the question. It didn't turn out to be relevant for me, but it could have. Good luck!